# Validate: String must only contain <div> Tags

Tags: c#, validation

How to validate, if a string contains any other HTML-Tag but `<div></div>`?

Need to see, does string contain other then `DIV` element or not.

What would be the best way to achieve this.

If anything to get this result by regex would be great but not sure to prepare regex for validate this scenario.

example for valid string:

```
This is the data received from external <div>data string</div>. string <div>valid string</div>
```

Invalid string because it contains a HTML Tag that isn't `<div>`:

```
This is the data received from external <p>data string</p>. string <div>valid string</div>
```

Comment: Show us your attempt, input string and expected output

Comment: Are you saying you need to check if a string contains other than `<div> </div>` tags?

Comment: Yes. Only allowing `div` but, any other thing exists or not, that is what want to check.

Comment: I never miss an opportunity to link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/860585

Comment: @Rotem nice, I couldn't find that post; honestly I was going to write a comment about not using regex for html parsing, but couldn't find that post!

Comment: So, better would be writing, parsing logic to extract all nodes between `<` and `>` and check, whether its a DIV or not.

Comment: How to fetch only value between, to use with expression like `/<[^>]*>/g` ?

Comment: @dsi consider [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4099159) as a good reference when trying to parse htm with regex.

Comment: @rotem dammn i was too late

Answer (score 2):

You need to Install [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) using the node package manager Console.

`install-package htmlagilitypack`

Then you can use it like this:

```
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var validstring =
            "This is the data received from external<div> data string</ div >. string <div>valid string</ div >";
        var invalidstring =
            "This is the data received from external <p>data string</p>. string <div>valid string</div>";

        var b1 = IsStringValid(validstring); // returns true
        var b2 = IsStringValid(invalidstring); // returns false
    }

    static bool IsStringValid(string str)
    {
        var pageDocument = new HtmlDocument(); // Create HtmlDocument
        pageDocument.LoadHtml(str); // Load the string into the Doc

        // check if the descendant nodes only have the names "div" and "#text"
        // "#text" is the name of any descendant that isn't inside a html-tag
        return !pageDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().Any(node => node.Name != "div" && node.Name != "#text");
    }
```

Comment: I've also looked into parsing it with XmlReaders, but using `HtmlAgilityPack` seems to be the most convenient way.

Comment: @dsi if this solves your issue, feel free to accept the answer. if not, please tell me your doubts.